# Video (generated with FFMPEG) scrambled in Chrome after upload to YouTube

Tags: ffmpeg, youtube

I am generating short videos from screenshots (e.g. 900 screenshots for a 30 seconds clip) with ffmpeg.

It works great and I can play the videos in different video players on Windows without a problem. When I upload the video to my YouTube channel it still works fine in the small preview under studio.youtube.com. But as soon as I preview the video on YouTube the whole video is "scrambled" (see attached image).

Other YouTube videos uploaded by other users play fine in my Chrome.

I am using Chrome and if I deactivate Hardware Acceleration in Chrome settings the video plays fine on YouTube. But that obviously is not a viable solution. Users should be able to watch the videos on YouTube without changing settings.

The video also plays fine in the Android YouTube app and in Firefox on Windows.

I have tried a lot of settings for ffmpeg - no success.

This is one of the commands I have tried. The parameters are supposed to be according to YouTube's best practice requirements:

```
ffmpeg -r 30 -s 1080x1920 -i storage/screenshot-%03d.jpg -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:v libx264 -profile:v high -preset slow -crf 18 -g 30 -bf 2 storage/testvideo.mp4
```

Has anybody experienced this problem with ffmpeg generated YouTube videos on Chrome and solved the problem? Any idea appreciated.

[image]